# Sum of columnA where another columnB is specific value without showing columnB

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that I'm grouping data together from. I'm running into a problem where I want the sum of a number from Column2 where Column3 has a specific value without showing Column3

Table X:

```
Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
 A     4    tt    6y
 B     5    tt    6y
 C     4    ee    7y
 A     3    ee    7u 
 A     4    ee    6y
 B     5    tt    8u
 C     4    tt    7y
 A     3    xx    8u
```

My Select grouping is

```
select Col1, Sum(Col2), Col4
from table x
group by Col1, Col4
```

I need to add 2 new columns in the group, the sum of column Col2 where Col3 is tt and another is the sum of Col2 where Col3 is ee. I do not need to show the value of Col3 and do not want to group by Col3.

I have looked at a partition by but I can't figure out how to specify the partition to the value of the column.

Comment: Help us help you - what's the expected result for this sample data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need conditional aggregation:

```
Select
  Col1, Col4,
  Sum(Col2) sumcol2,
  Sum(case when col3 = 'tt' then Col2 else 0 end) sumtt,
  Sum(case when col3 = 'ee' then Col2 else 0 end) sumee
from table x
group by Col1,Col4
```

Answer (score 0):

Use HAVING in the similar way as WHERE condition while grouping. 
Something like:

```
SELECT Col1,Sum(Col2),Col4
FROM table x
GROUP BY Col1,Col4
HAVING COl3 LIKE 'ee'
```

As I am not sitting at my SQL machine, I cannot test it - test it yoursef.